# How to call Objective C++ function with C++ arguments?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I have the following files:

- MyCppClass.cpp - Pure C++
- MyObjCppClass.h - Pure C++ class definition with C++ function prototypes.
- MyObjCppClass.mm - C++ style functions with function bodies using ObjC. Has C++ style functions, not ObjC.

The pure C++ class includes the ObjC++ header and news up an instance of MyObjCppClass. I then try and call functions on the ObjCpp class. The issue is, when I try to call functions that take arguments.

If I call functions without arguments, everything is fine. However, if I try to call a function that takes arguments, I get symbols not found link errors when compiling. I initially thought name mangling but thought this wouldn't be the issue since both are plain C++. I get the same error even if I remove the ObjC from the bodies. I was curious if I was missing a step?

It is important to note that the arguments that I am passing in have references to pure C++ objects that are contained within a statically linked library. It only seems to be a problem when used as an argument since I can use them within the function bodies with no problem.

I am using Xcode 6.4, C++11, and Clang.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without any code it's hard to tell what's going on. Are you using templates at all?

Comment: What symbols are not found? Are they ObjC classes? C++ classes? System things? Is there a .m file somewhere that also includes one of the headers? Does your ObjC++ header perhaps include or use ObjC stuff? We really can't help without more information or even better (minimal) sample code that exhibits the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I should have added more information and code. Turns out, it was a silly mistake on my part.

I had forgotten to include the name of the class followed by two colons before the function name which had the arguments.

So the problem I had was this:

```
void functionThatTakesArgs(SomeClass& someClass) { }
```

when what I should really have had was this:

```
MyObjCppClass::functionThatTakesArgs(SomeClass& someClass) { }
```

Hope this helps someone. Happened to be a silly mistake.